# Must Implement inherited Abstract Method Error Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, button, window

[click the link to see my code from .imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGdVJ.png)
Hello, I've been working on this project for weeks. I have just about 20 tabs open, trying to learn about windows, and buttons etc. I have a lot of questions. Primarily, what does this error mean? (refer to the image) How do i fix it? The goal here is, very simply, to have a button appear on a window: 600x450 resolution. I've tried so many things, and am just very stumped, I want to learn. Please help. How do I create a button, what does this error message mean? I've yet to come across a YouTube Video or help page that has identified all the components of a window. Everything is scrambled. I will immensely appreciate a helpful response.

Comment: When a light bulb is displayed, put the cursor to the error, hit Ctrl+1 (Quick Fix) and Eclipse suggests how you can fix the error. [WindowBuilder](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/windowbuilder) could be helpful when designing Java Swing UIs.

Comment: I know of that functionality, my question remains unsolved.

Comment: In the bottom of your editor there is a tab called Problems.
There all compiler errors and warnings are listed. Together with a short description of the problem.

Sadly in the image you provided the we can only see a part of the error message.
In future please provide these error messages in your questions.
To your problem: you are not implementing the methods of `ActionListener`. To solve this you need to implement all [methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) of this interface.

Comment: Yes, part of the problem here is that i do not know what those error messages mean. The error message at the bottom was the whole message, the only one. You said i needed to implement this code: ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent) correct? What does that code do? How would it effect me and whats its purpose. I am trying to learn. I really do not understand how to add a button, have patience, can you explain all this to me?

Comment: First of all you need to see entire error message (and preferably include it in your question as text, instead of image - [more info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)). For now your image shows only *beginning* of error message that is `The type Button1 must implement the inherit`. After that we have `Button1` but that is *not* part of error message, but name of *resource* from which this error comes from (see column names). So try to widen `Description` column and copy its content, [edit] your question and paste it there.

Comment: In line 24 you set the `ActionListener` for the button `b2` to `this`. `this` refers to the instance of the class `Button1` which correctly is specified as `implements ActionListener`, but this means also `Button1` must have the method `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` which will be called if the button is pressed (e. g. put `System.out.println("Button pressed!")` inside the method). The error means that this method is missing. You can add the method or remove `implements ActionListener` and line 24, but then no code will be executed if you press the button.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand the concept of inheriting (extend) a class and implementing an interface in Java. When you inherit a class, the class might some methods which are abstract which must be implemented by the derived class. In case of extending an interface, all its methods should be implemented.

in your case: ActionListener is an interface and you need to implement:
ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent). This is an abstract method.

Please refer for more details:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Comment: I still don't understand, I'm trying to. What would that abstract method's purpose be? What does it do? I tried removing implements ActionListener { to no avail. If i remove this, then b1.AddActionListener(this); stops working. There has to be some way i can rewrite my code. Keep in mind, I only want the button to appear, and be able to be pressed. I want it on a 600x450 window.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are trying to create a windows application using Java in eclipse. If you want to develop an application using Swing: you need to go through the process of developing it. Please refer to the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/  If you want to develop a window with a button on it. Java swing ApplicationWindow will help.

Comment: No, an application is not my intention. I wrote it down in my question and my reply, I do not want to create an application. "Keep in mind, I only want the button to appear, and be able to be pressed. I want it on a 600x450 window" -27 minutes ago. I appreciate your willingness to help although you didn't know how to code buttons. Thank you for responding.